# Loading a jquery dependant script in Wordpress (causing issues)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I need to load a js script in my Wordpress theme. This script is dependent on jquery 1.11.1.

I am trying to use a code in functions.php so that I can load my script and make it dependant on jquery 1.11.1. 
I read that I need to load it in non-conflict mode so that it doesn't cause problems on the site.

With my current code, everything works perfect on the front-end of the site, but it weirdly causes stuff in the Wordpress dashboard to misbehave...

I have limited JS and PHP knowledge... I would appreciate it if someone can please explain what I'm doing wrong...

Here's my code:

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery1.11.1', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' , array(), null );
wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery1.11.1', 'var jquery1.11.1 = $.noConflict(true);' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'expand.js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/expand.js', array( 'jquery1.11.1' ));
```

Comment: Do you need the script on WP admin? If not why not just conditionally load it to the front-end. Otherwise your approach is solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expound on my comment, you could check whether WP is attempting to load the admin page. If it is not, you can enqueue the script. Something like:

```js
wp_register_script( 'jquery1.11.1', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' , array(), null );

if (!is_admin()) {
   wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery1.11.1', 'var jquery1.11.1 = $.noConflict(true);' );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'expand.js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/expand.js', array( 'jquery1.11.1' ));
}
```

Check out [is_admin()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) for more info/caveats

Comment: Thanks so much for replying to my question... I am not trying to load it in the admin control panel... I actually want to load it on the front end... am I using the incorrect code then? Your help is very appreicated xx

Comment: Np. I modified your code a little by adding the `is_admin()` conditional. This makes it so that your script is loaded on the front-end only.